# Does using many XML parsers (XDocument, XMLDocument) from the public Internet increase attack surface area?

Tags: appsec, asp.net, wcf, xml, buffer-overflow

I am coding an anonymous WCF service that allows others to post XML into it.

Does using different kinds of XML parsers `XDocument, XMLDocument`, or even 3rd party parsers increase the attack surface area? (Buffer overflows, etc).

Comment: Related: [XML Encryption Vulnerability](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8328/396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  By definition, allowing user interaction with additional software increases the [Attack surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface).

Comment: Exactly.  The more things, the more things that can be broken.